# Python audio player module who can use 2 sound card

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, libvlc, pygobject

( i am French, excuse my english :p )

I use Python 3 and GTK3

I would like to do in Python, a music player that could use 2 sound card. For example playing a music on the speaker and another on my screen. (or a music played by mixer track)

Do you know a module that can play sound on several sound cards? for now I'm using a VLC port for python. But I do not think this module is the ability to play on multiple cards? (or even to be able to select it with python code?)

Comment: This question is pretty broad. Could you be more specific about what you have tried and the result you are getting? Showing some code is usually helpful.

Comment: hi ! 

I want play a music on my first soundcard and play a second music on another device

I look for a module python for play sound ( mp3, wav, flac ... ). A module can play of many device. 

libvlc can use many device, but i don't know how :/

Comment: I know how to play a sound ( mp3, flac ... ) on my speaker ( the first audio device ) but i would like play sound on another device 

My English is corect ? :)